# Detect absence of JRE to warn when user tries to start my web-start-launched program

Tags: java, deployment, java-web-start

I use java Web Start to launch my program.  My web site has a link with url pointing to the jnlp file that kicks off the application.  This works great IF users have java installed. Otherwise, they get all tangled up when their OS asks them: how do you want to open this file?  I'd like to warn users who don't have java installed before they click the link, or perhaps when they click the link, to the jnlp file.

In the good 'ol days, I could use methods in a small library named deployJava.js, but now it seems they don't work -- at least not for tests on Chrome or Safari.  I think that may be due to the tests relying on the 'plug-in,' which is no longer supported.

So all that to say: does anyone have a way to use javascript to probe for the presence of a JRE?

Answer (score 1):

The only available remedy<sup>1</sup> these days is something like:

```
Click here <a href='the.jnlp>Install/launch the app.</a><br>
This app. requires the <a href='..'>Java Plug-In</a>.
```

1. If your users are motivated, this will work just fine in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I was afraid of that!